# How to get scrolling in edittext when it is inside scrollview?

Tags: android

In my application i am using EditText to write the Mail description and i made it as per following.
My edittext has multiple lines.
When i am entering more lines and try to move from bottom to up in edittext at that time scrolling of edittext is not working.

Can anybody help me ?
Thanks..

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edBody"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="5"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="" 
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>    


    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: hi can you please help me if you find any solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Loooooooooonng loooooooooong teeeeeeeeeeext"
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:maxLines = "100"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText et;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        et.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    }
}
```

NOTE: You cannot put scrollable control (for example ListView) in ScrollView. And I think it does not work with scrollable EditText into ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it may works

```
EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edbody);
et.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

in your activity

Answer (score 0):

First Create your id for your scrollview and then after write this code in your method.

```
et.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                mScrollMain.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

cahnge Hear mScrollMain with your scrollview object .
they work definitely